# Who assigns a key in the key-value store nosql database?

Tags: nosql, key-value-store

In many white papers I've read, it is stated that in key value stores (hash table implementation), the key is assigned by the system to a key value pair. However, in others, it is given that a user assigns it.

My questions:

- If the system assigns it, how does the user know what the key is?
- How does the user refer to a pair?

Comment: http://ianvarley.com/UT/MR/Varley_MastersReport_Full_2009-08-07.pdf

Comment: That document is 108 pages. Could you tell us the page number(s)?